# Can I change gitlab-ci.yml file mid execution?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

This is our simplified gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages: 
    - build
    - deploy

# fetch home repo that'll run the pipeline processes
before_script:
    - git clone git@git.org:home_repo/home_repo.git
    - cd home_repo

build:
  stage: build
  needs: []
  resource_group: $CI_PROJECT_NAME'_build'
  script:
    - ./pipeline.sh build

deploy_environment1:
  stage: deploy
  needs: [build]
  resource_group: deploy_environment1
  script:
    - ./pipeline.sh deploy env1

deploy_environment2:
  stage: deploy
  needs: [build]
  resource_group: deploy_environment2
  script:
    - ./pipeline.sh deploy env2
```

Adding 5-10 environments would blow up the size by a lot. How can we handle that?

**Possible solution 1:**
Have one job that will create a list of all environments available and deploy to them. However, we won't have a good pipeline view of how each deployment went.

```
deploy_environments:
  stage: deploy
  needs: [build]
  resource_group: deploy_environments
  script:
    - ./pipeline.sh deploy to_all
```

**Possible solution 2:**
`before_script` fetches a list of all environments and inserts as many `deploy_environment` job definitions as needed. But we don't know how to do that. Hence the question in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I change gitlab-ci.yml file mid execution?

No, not *really*. The closest thing to that would be using [dynamic child pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines) where the YAML for a [child pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html) is generated dynamically by another job in the parent pipeline.

That would allow you to achieve the effect you want.

> Adding 5-10 environments would blow up the size by a lot. How can we handle that?

Alternative to (or even in combination with) using dynamic child pipelines, you could use a [parallel matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallelmatrix) for concise definitions.

Something like this:

```yaml
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ./pipeline.sh deploy $ENV_NAME
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ENV_NAME: [env1, env2]
```